# Failed prop type: Material-UI: Either `children`, `image`, `src` or `component` prop must be specified

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I kept getting this error even though I have an image prop in CardMedia

Code

[image: 1]

Error description

[image: 2]

This is a snippet of the code.

```html
const Post  = ({ post, setter }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
        <Card className={classes.card}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={post.selectedFile}  title={post.title} />
            <div className={classes.overlay}>
                <Typography variant='h6' >{post.creator}</Typography>
                <Typography variant='body2' >{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</Typography>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.overlay2}>
                <Button style={{color:'white'}} size='small' onClick={() => setter(post._id)}>
                    <MoreHorizIcon fontSize='medium' />
                </Button>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.details}>
                <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' >{post.tags.map((tag) => `#${tag} `)}</Typography>
            </div>
            <Typography className={classes.title} variant='h5' gutterBottom>{post.title}</Typography>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography  variant='h5' gutterBottom>{post.message}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
                <Button size='small' color='primary' onClick={() => {}}>
                    <ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize='small' />
                    like
                    {post.likeCount}
                </Button>
                <Button size='small' color='primary' onClick={() => {}}>
                    <DeleteIcon fontSize='small' />
                    Delete
                </Button>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    );
}
```

I'm new to full stack dev and am following a tutorial by JSMastery which has so far been good. I got this error and im confused. It might be a simple fix but I dont know what information you guys would need to resolve it so please comment if you need more info.

Comment: Please post some code and not only the images, and you shoul include the CardMedia code too

Comment: Other props would be mandatory. I am hoping this is MUI CardMedia component.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only reason for this is that provided `media` is either `null` or `undefined`

Comment: when i compile it, it somehow displays the image but the error reduces other functionalities

Comment: Not enough data to make some strong assumptions. It would be more helpful if you add some live examples or more source code. Image may be displayed, because props may change. On the first render probably there were no images and an error message has been shown, on the second render the component got the image and rendered it.

Comment: i have added a snippet, please do check it out.